# C++ Arduino passing char* to an array of char*

Tags: c++, arduino, teensy

I am having a problem with passing a `char*` to an array of `char**` on my Teensy.

Below is the problematic part:

```
for (j = 0; j < rulesamountsingle; j++) {
   emptybuffer(buff);
   char temp[10];
   while(!Serial.available());
   len = Serial.available();
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
     temp[i] = Serial.read();
   }
   temp[len-1] = 0;
   fuzzyRulesSingle[j] = temp;
   Serial.print(fuzzyRulesSingle[j]);
   Serial.print('\n');
 }
```

As you can see, `fuzzyRulesSingle[j]` (where `fuzzyRulesSingle` is a `char**`) will be filled by the variable `temp` (a `char*`). As I increment `j`, the next address in `fuzzyRulesSingle` will be filled by a new `temp`.

However, when I print my `fuzzyRulesSingle` OUTSIDE the code above, all `fuzzyRulesSingle` will be filled with the last value of temp.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: You reuse `temp` over and over so `fuzzyRulesSingle[j]` always points to the same place. You need to copy the chars in `temp` into `fuzzyRulesSingle[j]` - allocating space first.

Comment: Can you show us the definition of fuzzyRulesSingle object. Is it an array of pointers or arrays?

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing `fuzzyRulesSingle[j]` to the temporary char array `temp`.
A simple way to fix this is to change the `fuzzyRulesSingle[j] = temp;` to `strcpy(fuzzyRulesSingle[j], temp)` and changing the declaration of `fuzzzyRulessSingle` to the size required.

OR

you can declare `temp` outsize the loop and use `malloc` to allocate memory necessary and then assign it to `fuzzyRulesSingle[j]`